# Integrals: arccos and arcsin relationship

Tags: calculus, integration

Let's assume I have this simple integral:

$\int \frac{-6}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx = -6 \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = -6\arcsin{x} + C$

Question is: can I also write down the result as: $6\arccos{x}+C?$

And thus would the following be true?

$\int \frac{a}{\sqrt{b^2-x^2}}dx = a\arcsin{\frac{x}{b}} +C = -a\arccos{\frac{x}{b}}+C$

Comment: It may be best not to write $a\arcsin{\frac{x}{b}} +C = -a\arccos{\frac{x}{b}}+C$ since the $C$ on the left is not equal to the $C$ on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (to the first question), since $(-\arcsin)'=\arccos'$. And the answer to the second question is also affirmative.

Answer (score 1):

$$ -\arccos(x) \equiv \arcsin(x)-\frac{\pi}{2} = \arcsin(x) + C$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is true. $$(\arccos x)'=\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin x\right)'=-(\arcsin x)'$$